# How to color each column differently in plot function?

Tags: r, plot, colors, color-palette

I have a data frame as follows:

```
       A          B        C        D          E        F        
T1     1          0        4        6          2        5      
T2     1          0        4        6          2        5        
T3     1          0        4        6          2        5        
T4     1          0        4        6          2        5
```

I'm doing an ordination and I just want each column to have a different color and have a corresponding legend.

```
points(dat.pcoa$points[ ,1], dat.pcoa$points[ ,2],
   pch = 19, cex = 3, bg = "gray", col = "gray")
```

I have this code written out, put I don't know how to assign a pallet to this as I have a large range of data points, so I cannot assign a vector `(c <- "red","blue")` as it would be a tedious excercise

Comment: [An example with `ggplot2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36388031/2204410)

Comment: The nice thing about ggplot2 is that it has different layers and more examples found online w.r.t. to that and use of pallet. However, I need to do my plots in basic R (long reason) and I need a pallet because of the sheer number of columns I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RColorBrewer` package has some ready made palettes, but if your aim is base R only, you can try building one yourself. There are several base functions that produce color strings - I suggest using `hsv()`, because it is easier to produce diverse colors of same saturation, while `rgb()` would require changing all three arguments.

For example, producing 10 colors with hues 0.1 to 1, maintaining saturation and brightness at 0.7:

```
barplot(1:10, col=sapply(1:10/10, hsv, 0.7, 0.7))
```

[image: colorful barplot]

---

EDIT: `rainbow` seems to be a built-in wrapper to do exactly that - calling `hsv` to produce a desired number of colors. Thanks @d.b !

Comment: Maybe mention `rainbow` too